# Where does github actions stores the log files?

Tags: android, github, github-actions, pipeline, github-ci

On my github action, it logged the following:

```
The full lint text report is located at:
  /home/runner/work/honk/honk/app/build/intermediates/lint_intermediate_text_report/debug/lint-results-debug.txt
```

`honk` is the name of my repo, but where do I find the `lint-results-debug.txt` file?

This is how my `android.yml` file is configured:

```
name: Android CI

on: [ pull_request ]

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 1.11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.11

      - name: Change wrapper permissions
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew

      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew build

      - name: Run tests
        run: ./gradlew test

      - name: Upload app to AppSweep with Gradle
        env:
          APPSWEEP_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.APPSWEEP_API_KEY }}
        run: ./gradlew uploadToAppSweepRelease
```

Answer (score 0):

The Github Doc [`Using workflow run logs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/using-workflow-run-logs#downloading-logs), says the following about `finding/downloading` logs created by `workflows`:

> You can download the log files from your workflow run. You can also
> download a workflow's artifacts. For more information, see ["Storing
> workflow data as artifacts."](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts) Read access to the repository is required
> to perform these steps.

You can follow the rest of the steps to find and download your desired files.

Comment: Downloading the logs does not list all the lint errors, only the same text you can see in Github.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it gets discarded, they don't save any logs, if you don't save them intentionally.

You can do that with this action. *Notice the Upload Lint Report*

```
jobs:
  build-and-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 1.11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.11

      - name: Change wrapper permissions
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew

      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew build

      - name: Run tests
        run: ./gradlew test
      
      - name: Upload Lint Report to Github
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: nightly
          path: app/build/intermediates/lint_intermediate_text_report/debug/lint-results-debug.txt
          retention-days: 10
#       rest of the script
```

Though if you are just looking for the report, because of failed, you should get that in the console output with searching *Failed*.

Comment: I updated my question. Based on my yml file, where should I put it?

Comment: I updated the answer. I am not sure which of test or build is running the lint though, but it should be safe to put it after both of them